# extjs embed bar chart series inside Ext.grid.panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Is there a way to draw/visualize integer data as a series bar chart instead of as a number **inside an Ext.panel.grid**?

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.define('spaceManager', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [{
            name: 'type'
        }, {
            name: 'totalRecsCnt',
            type: 'int'
        }, {
            name: 'usedRecsCnt',
            type: 'int'
        }, {
            name: 'dSize',
            type: 'int'
        }]
    });

    var grid2 = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: getLocalStore(),
        selModel: sm,
        columns: [{
            text: "Type",
            width: 100,
            dataIndex: 'type'
        }, {
            text: "Total Records Count",
            dataIndex: 'totalRecCnt'
        }, {
            text: "Used Records Count",
            dataIndex: 'usedRecCnt'
        }, {
            text: "Disk Size",
            width: 135,
            dataIndex: 'dSize'
        }],
        columnLines: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 300,
        frame: true,
        title: 'Space Manager',
        iconCls: 'icon-grid',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```

What i'm trying to do is draw bars for the dSize field from the spaceManager model - the dSize column should be drawn as a bar chart series of data rather than displayed as a list of numbers.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5719/labeling-a-multi-layered-bar-graph